What is the source of this śloka starting with "viprāṇāṃ daivataṃ śambhuḥ"?

विप्राणां दैवतं शम्भुः क्षत्रियाणां च माधवः ।
वैश्यानां तु भवेद् ब्रह्मा शूद्राणां गणनायकः ॥

"Śiva is the deity of the Brāhmaṇas, Viṣṇu of the Kṣatriyas, Brahmā of the Vaiśyas, and Gaṇeśa of the Śūdras."

On simple internet search it is showing a shloka from Shri Shankara Digvijayam Anantananda Giri Praneetam (श्रीशङ्करविजयम् – अनन्तानन्दगिरिप्रणीतम्).
It may be the original source or it may be a quotation of another scripture.

विप्राणां दैवतं शम्भुः क्षत्रियाणां च माधवः ।
वैश्यानां तु भवेद्ब्रह्मा शूद्राणां गणनायकः ॥
Source link 1, link 2


Says manusmriti. But it's not there

@Śipiviṣṭa it says only Smriti. Someone maybe has suggested Manu Smriti, that's why it is in the bracket.

The śloka starting with "viprāṇāṃ daivataṃ śambhuḥ" is found in the Mahabharata, specifically in the Shanti Parva (Book of Peace), Section CLXV (165), verse 14. This verse is part of a conversation between Bhishma and Yudhishthira, where Bhishma imparts various teachings and instructions on dharma (righteousness) and governance.
Here is the śloka with its transliteration and translation:
Sanskrit:
विप्राणां दैवतं शम्भुः क्षत्रियाणां च वीर्यवान्।
वैश्यानां धनवान्वार्यो शूद्राणां सेवको नृपः॥
Transliteration:
viprāṇāṃ daivataṃ śambhuḥ kṣatriyāṇāṃ ca vīryavān
vaiśyānāṃ dhanavānvāryo śūdrāṇāṃ sevako nṛpaḥ
Translation:
"Among the learned, Shambhu (Shiva) is their deity; among the warriors, the courageous; among merchants, wealth; and among servants, the king."
This verse highlights the respective ideals and deities associated with different varnas (social classes) in ancient Indian society, emphasizing the roles and attributes valued within each group.

Can you link the verse with source? I couldn't find it in sanskritdocuments.org
